# Node JS run using Cron Job on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron

I am trying to run a node script on an AWS Ubuntu server. When I log into the Ubuntu server from my terminal and run my script with the command "node dacDev.js" it works just fine. The script writes to a log file in another folder. I want to run this with a cron command on AWS, but it won't run. Here is what my cron job says.

"* * * * * /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/bin/node /home/ubuntu/getmyteatime/cronjob.sh"

The file cronjob.sh contains the absolute path of the node script. It reads:

node /home/ubuntu/getmyteatime/dacDev.js
Nothing runs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run it as the [ubuntu user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505181/how-to-run-a-cron-job-as-a-specific-user).

Comment: @jarmod I looked at the link you attached. Where would I put this line: sudo -u <username> in my cron command?

Comment: Use `sudo -u ubuntu command` in crontab instead of `command`.

Comment: @jarmod So in the cronjob.sh file put `sudo -u ubuntu node /home/ubuntu/getmyteatime/dacDev.js` ?

Comment: Worth reading: https://serverfault.com/questions/352835/crontab-running-as-a-specific-user

Answer (score 0):

For the node, you also need an absolute path to run any.js file. This is achievable but rather than running with node try to write a script and do the following:

```bash
echo $PATH # /path/to/env
which npm # /path/to/npm
```

#### Paste below lines when the command `crontab -e` is executed.

```bash
PATH=/path/to/env
* * * * * cd /path/to/app && path/to/npm run script >>/tmp/crontab.log 2>&1
```

- `>>/tmp/crontab.log 2>&1` -- means, it will log the result to this path for debugging purposes.